# Jquery datatable present details

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, datatable

I have a jQuery DataTable powered by a JSON return that has detail, where it clicks on the row and expands the detail tamplate loading a list from my JSON, to do this I followed that [example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html).

I would like to know how to load the detail without hiding it, as if it were a sequence of the datatable line, can not have the option to expand and collapse, the detail must always be visible

```
Column1| Column2| Column3|
Value1   Value2   Value3
  Detail1| Detail2| Detail3|
  ValueD1   ValueD2   ValueD3
```

**UPDATE - JSON**

```
$scope.list = [
            {
                id:1,
                name: "Ze",
                listDetail: [
                    {
                        id:1,
                        description: "lt"
                    },
                    {
                        id:2,
                        description: "lt 3"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                id:2,
                name: "Ze 2",
                listDetail: [
                    {
                        id:3,
                        description: "lt 1"
                    },
                    {
                        id:4,
                        description: "lt 4"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ];
```

Comment: I'll say you do a normal datatable,but just for your detailed row, you add an attribute to the td : `colspan=nbOfColumn` and put your details in the td.

Comment: I am starting to study this world of angularjs, jquery among others, I tried to search for `colspan=nbOfColumn`.  but I did not find anything concrete that could help me, do you have any examples?

Comment: Can you give me an example of your JSON? Are you working server side ? Are you the one generating the JSON?

Comment: I edited the post and added the JSON return. Yes, this JSON value is coming from the server

Comment: Is the number of detail rows under each normal row fixed?

Comment: No, the number of detail lines is not fixed, it may vary according to the main record. The master record is loaded by one view, and the detail records are loaded by another view. Parents and sons

Answer (score 0):

Here, it should work:

Here, is a solution that should work with a JSON like that:

- json

`{
    "draw": 2,
    "recordsTotal": 3,
    "recordsFiltered": 3,
    "data": [{
        "type": "normal",
        "description": "Zenaida",
        "name": "Frank",
        "age": "Software Engineer",
        "location": "New York"
    }, {
        "type": "detail",
        "detail": "first detail"
    }, {
        "type": "detail",
        "detail": "second detail"
    }, {
        "type": "detail",
        "detail": "third detail"
    }, {
        "type": "normal",
        "description": "zerrz",
        "name": "paul",
        "age": "Software breaker",
        "location": "Lodon"
    }, {
        "type": "detail",
        "detail": "third detail"
    }, {
        "type": "normal",
        "description": "Zenaida",
        "name": "Frank",
        "age": "Software Engineer",
        "location": "New York"
    }, {
        "type": "detail",
        "detail": "second detail"
    }, {
        "type": "detail",
        "detail": "third detail"
    }]
}`

- js

`$('#example').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "YourAjaxSource",
    "columns": [ //You have to manually bind your column since the first value is not to be displayed
        {
            "data": "details"
        },
        {
            "data": "description"
        },
        {
            "data": "name"
        },
        {
            "data": "age"
        },
        {
            "data": "location"
        }
    ],
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        switch (aData[0]) { //first value indicates if its a detail row or a normal row
            case 'normal': // if its a normal row, just display the cells without the first detail one
                $(nRow).find('td')[0].style.display = 'none';
                break;
            case 'detail': //else display none of the cells except the detail one with take up 5 cells
                $(nRow).find('td')[1].style.display = 'none';
                $(nRow).find('td')[2].style.display = 'none';
                $(nRow).find('td')[3].style.display = 'none';
                $(nRow).find('td')[4].style.display = 'none';
                $(nRow).find('td')[0].colSpan = '5'; //Your number of column
                break;
        }
    }
});`

The way it works is, each row technicly have the detail + the normal cells.

When drawing it check for each row the type of row, and display only the needed cells (since the others are empty)

Finally for the detail row I give an attribute colspan of the number of cell To allow it To take all the width of the row.

I haven't tested it so gl&hf ;) if you have any trouble don't hesitate to comment.

And adapt it to your need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've been tending to do according to your example and I did not succeed. From what I could tell from your example the JSON return is somewhat different from my JSON return, that I have a list inside another list, meaning my main content contains a list with detail content. The way you gave me the example I could not figure out how I could make it work, since your JSON is in a format different from mine.